# How to install .js file into Greasemonkey?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

Where is the ability to install custom GreaseMonkey scripts? I've installed greasemonkey. My dialog box under tools only has GreaseMonkey -> [Enabled, Manage User Scripts..., New User Scripts..., User Script Commands (greyed out)]

The "Manage User Scripts" dialog box is here: http://img182.imageshack.us/img182/5907/screenshotat.png

I'm using GreaseMonkey version 0.8.20090123.1 on Ubuntu Linux 8.04 (Jaunty) with Firefox 3.0.14

Comment: You should consider taking your update and making that an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the right answer here is to rename the file to a .user.js (literal) extension - which userscripts will do for you - and link to it in a webpage. There is no longer an Install Script dialog or anything of that sort that permits you to browse to a .js file and simply install. (that I know of)

Answer (score 5):

Use `Open File` from `File` menu and open the script. Greasemonkey will recognize it.

Comment: What is it about GreaseMonkey that inspires such mystery?  The official documentation gives no clue, and all of the other answers to this question were of no use.  This answer got me started, and I think I've figured the rest out from there.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a 'New User Scripts' option, like you mention, under your GreaseMonkey menu?

Comment: yes, but that is if you want to create a script, it makes like a boiler plate and opens up an external editor.

Comment: ...into which you can paste the script.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one from [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/), and you should be prompted to install it.